# Fortran: insufficient virtual memory

Tags: arrays, memory, memory-management, fortran

I - not a professional software engineer - am currently extending a quite large scientific software.
At runtime I get an error stating "insufficient virtual memory".

At this point during runtime, the used working memory is about 550mb and the error accurs when a rather big threedimensional array is dynamically allocated. The array - if it would be allocated - would be about a size of 170mb. Adding this to the already used 550mb the program would still be way below the 2gb boundary that is set for 32bit applications. Also there is more than enough working memory available on the system.
Visual Studio is currently set that it allocates arrays on the stack. Allocating them on the heap does not make any difference anyway.

Splitting the array into smaller arrays (being the size of the one big array in sum) results in the program running just fine. So I guess that the dynamically allocated memory has to be available in one adjacent block.

So there I am and I have no clue how to solve this. I can not deallocate some of the already used 550mb as the data is still required. I also can not change very much of the configuration (e.g. the compiler).
Is there a solution for my problem?

Thank you some much in advance and best regards

phroth248

Comment: You must show your code. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Also report your compiler version.

Comment: I can not really provide some thousand lines of code here. The line returning the error is as mentioned above just an allocation of an array:
`ALLOCATE (smthng(x,y,z))`

My Fortran compiler is: Intel(R) Visual Fortran Compiler XE 13.1.3.198

Comment: This is completely insufficient, how are the variables declared? Which values they have? Read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve again and read it carefully.

Comment: Which operating system is this on? Also, I'm a bit confused about the compiler. Are you using both Microsoft Visual studio and Intel fortran compiler?

Comment: Yes, I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 with Intel Visual Fortran Composer XE 2013. But anyway, I can not change the compiler.

Comment: The are declared just like dynamically allocatable arrays in a module with `REAL, ALLOCATABLE :: smthng(:,:,:)` and are working just fine with smaller sizes. I do not think that this is a coding issue. It seems to be more of a memory management issue.

Answer (score 1):

The virtual memory is the memory your program can address. It is usually the sum of the physical memory and the swap space. For example, if you have 16GB of physical memory and 4GB of swap space, the virtual memory will be 20GB. If your Fortran program tries to allocate more than those 20 addressable GB, you will get an "insufficient virtual memory" error.

To get an idea of the required memory of your 3D array:

```
allocate (A(nx,ny,nz))
```

You have `nx*ny*nz` elements and each element takes 8 bytes in double precision or 4 bytes in single precision. I let you do the math.

Comment: As I wrote above, my array needs 170mb. I got 550mb already used at this point at runtime. So after the allocation of the array I would need 720mb of memory, which should be no problem for any system nowadays.
Splitting the array into several smaller arrays results in NO error. Therefore leaving me with the assumption, that the memory has to be adjacent or in blocks or however one could call this.

Answer (score 0):

Some things:
1. It is usually preferable to to allocate huge arrays using operating system services rather than language facilities. That will circumvent any underlying library problems.

2. You may have a problem with 550MB in a 32-bit system. Usually there is some division of the 4GB address space into dedicated regions.
3. You need to make sure you have enough virtual memory.
   a) Make sure your page file space is large enough.
   b) Make sure that your system is not configured to limit processes address space sizes to smaller than what you need.
   c) Make sure that your accounts settings are not limiting your process address space to smaller than allowed by the system.

Comment: These are some points to work with. I really appreciate it. Thank you!
I guess point 2 is the issue here as it works to split the array into smaller arrays.
I am planning to write kind of a workaround some time in the sense of a function, that splitts huge arrays into smaller ones while allowing a handling of the big array in a usal manner.